# Setting base URL path of iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Is there any possible way (html, js, jquery) to change the base URL path of an `iframe`?

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a webpage that has a URL-entry field and a display area. The web app takes whatever URL the user enters, and then uses a special proxy service to retrieve the webpage that the user has specified. I then render this webpage in the display area using an iframe, where I insert the html source code into the `DOM` of the `iframe`. I do not use the `src` attribute because I am trying to demonstrate the functionality of my proxy service, and I don't want the browser to directly render the page itself.

The html source that I insert will load in the iframe, with one caveat. None of the images or other resources that use a relative pathname work because they reference the URL of my outer webpage as the base URL. For example, if my webpage is located at `www.me.com` and the user tries to load `www.google.com`, I can render the `html` source for `www.google.com`, but the main Google image does not load because the image tries to load from `www.me.com/image` rather than `www.google.com/image`.

Comment: because I didn't know that existed, but it's just what i'm looking for

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the proxy end insert this tag:

`<base href="http://pathtooriginalpage" />`

and that should do it.